Why use Wilcoxon sum rank test on the residuals of a Linear Regression for alpha diversity?
I was reading this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-66598-2 , and I am confused about the results on diversity https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-66598-2#Fig1. I don't understand why they used the wilcoxon test on residuals or which is the result to be taken into account.
They preformed a Wilcoxon rank-sum test on the residuals of linear regression analyses of observed species by age, but I thought tests on residuals were usually done to check model assumptions.So I am just wondering if there are other instances where residuals are tested.
Another thing that confuses me: "When we take out the variability explained by age no significant differences in microbial diversity were observed between non-T2DM and T2DM individuals.", But the graph (1B) says it is age adjusted. Does this mean taking out the variability explained by age is the same as adjusting for age?
So for the model they actually used (1G), which they mentioned is adjusted for age, should I take in account "The linear regression ... shows that age has an important effect over microbiome diversity (p value < 0.05; R2 = 0.16)", or the Wilcoxon test that shows no significant difference?
Thanks!
